# First in are the blackest of the black - first in are - meaning, usage

Tags: meaning

Source: http://theweek.com/article/index/259581/russia-masters-the-art-of-clandestine-warfare-against-ukraine

> **First in are** the blackest of the black: case officers for the intelligence community who operate without official cover, who recruit sources and assess the battlefield. Then, small units of special operations forces sneak in, sometimes blending in with the populace, ready to make trouble. Then, special forces units that specialize in "information operations" designed to induce anxiety and outrage among local populations follow a strategy that comes from the top of the government. The idea is to generate genuine indigenous protest movements. Vladimir Putin has an eye to history; if today he seeds the strands that bind ethnic Russians in Ukraine together, it doesn't matter whether it takes five months or five years for a revolution to foment.

How do you understand **first in are**?

Comment: I think it would be necessary to see the preceding paragraph to understand this peoperly.

Comment: WS2 - that makes no sense.  "first in" is a commonplace military phrase.

Comment: @WS: everybody understands that "First in are the blackest of the black" refers to a military operation by Russia in Ukraine! (or so I have recently learned).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**"first in"** is simply a **military phrase**.

It's that simple.

It means the first to touch the ground during an invasion or deployment - as stib says the "first to be deployed".

Note that normally it would perhaps apply to a more immediate, specific, physical, situation (Example, "during the beach landing who was first in ... actually it was 4th regiment who hit the beach first.")

Here they are using it in a slightly more general way, since they are talking about spying and intelligence and so on.

(For example, if the "first in" is some internet intelligence unit, for example, they may not even literally be "on the ground" but be the first ones working in relation to the endeavour.)

Comment: So "First in were the soccer mums, eager to judge the results of the bake-off, then their tired husbands, appointed to carry those results home" describes a military operation? :D

Comment: Obviously the phrase can be used in other fields of endeavour, perhaps humorously. This is no more amazing than that I could say "Next the dads invaded the kitchen" or "The mom strike-force really hit home in the kitchen" and so on.

Comment: -1 for lack of source of the claim that the phrase is strictly military. Google shows it is widely used, also outside the military.

Comment: Note that say "lead the charge" is a "military phrase" and "hold all the aces" is a gambling phrase. Of course, obviously, these phrases are widely used in general in English.

Comment: I don't see why _first in_ needs to be military. _Lead the charge_ is very different and obviously military but _first in_ could well have a different origin.

Answer (score 1):

In this context I think it means "the first things to be deployed in a particular area or situation".

I think it's saying that the first intelligence operatives to be sent in to the Ukraine will be the ones who operate without official cover.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence can be paraphrased as:

> **The first ones to arrive** are the blackest of the black:

In this case, the author describes who the first people are to enter the theatre of operations in Ukraine.

"First in" can be read as a short form of *the first ones that are in*; to understand what "in" means, you have to depend on context.

Comment: The answer is basically totally wrong.  "first in" is a military phrase meaning the first engaged in a landing or other incursion.  For example when you say "to understand what "in" means, you have to depend on context" - that is completely and totally incorrect. The phrase has a well-known and common meaning.  (To wit, it's a military phrase meaning first to touch ground in a landing, first group or team involved in an incursion.)